# setExactAndAllowOnIdle doesnt trigger right

Tags: java, android

I have a problem using **setExactAndAllowOnIdle**. In my **AlarmReceiver** class I just show simple notification that shows when alarm was triggered and set another, same alarm but hour after.***(currentTimeMillis + 60*60*1000)***. When my phone is in use application works fine, alarms come exactly on time. But when I let it work for few alarms without waking device up, they start to trigger with few minutes delays, or sometimes even exactly on time I wake up my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().

You didn't tell on which OS are You testing it but probably it's because of Doze Mode.

**NOTICE:**

> Neither setAndAllowWhileIdle() nor setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() can
>   fire alarms more than once per 9 minutes, per app.

**So You can't use this method to set every alarm what probably You doing.**

For more information You can go here:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html